# What does const K& k = K() mean in this constructor function?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am having difficulty understanding the syntax of this code fragment

What is the purpose of "const K& k = K(), const V& v = V()"?

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class Entry{

    public:
        typedef K Key;
        typedef V Value;
    public:
        Entry(const K& k = K(), const V& v = V()) : _key(k), _value(v) {}

    ....
        ....
            ....
    private:
        K _key;
        V _value;
};
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what a reference is?  Do you know what a default function parameter is?  If not you should get a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: it's c++ template syntax. K and V can be any type of class or structure.

Comment: this is injecting instance of K and V into class's private property

Comment: @jesuisgenial c++ class members are not called "properties" and calling default parameters to a constructor "injection" may lead to confusion too imho

Comment: @jesuisgenial template type parameters can be any type

Comment: you guys are right. i'm a bit confused too. thanks for revise

Answer (score 1):

`K` and `V` are template parameters, they can be any data type the user of `Entry` wants.

`k` and `v` are input parameters of the `Entry` constructor.  They are being passed in by const reference, and they have default values specified, where `K()` default-constructs a temp object of type `K`, and `V()` default-constructs a temp object of type `V`.  If the user does not provide explicit input values when creating an `Entry` object instance, the defaults are used instead.

For example:

```
Entry<int, int> e1(1, 2);
// K = int, k = 1
// V = int, v = 2

Entry<int, int> e2(1);
// aka Entry<int, int> e2(1, int())
// K = int, k = 1
// V = int, v = 0

Entry<int, int> e3;
// aka Entry<int, int> e3(int(), int())
// K = int, k = 0
// V = int, v = 0

Entry<std::string, std::string> e4("key", "value");
// K = std::string, k = "key"
// V = std::string, v = "value"

Entry<std::string, std::string> e5("key");
// aka Entry<std::string, std::string> e4("key", std::string())
// K = std::string, k = "key"
// V = std::string, v = ""

Entry<std::string, std::string> e6;
// aka Entry<std::string, std::string> e4(std::string(), std::string())
// K = std::string, k = ""
// V = std::string, v = ""
```

Comment: It might not hurt to talk about what the syntax `K()` and `V()` mean, since I think the OP doesn't know you can do that.